# Smooth transition of images when swiping in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, image, jquery-mobile

I have an array of image URLs in an Image view.
I scroll the picture using swipe and that works for me.
In swipe function I am dynamically calling the images from the image array.
But the problem is that the image transition is not smooth.I need the image transition as slide.

**Code:**

```
var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>";
```

**Code from comment:**

```
$("#ImageDiv").swiperight(function () { 
  if (i < (imgURL.length - 1)) { 
    i++ 
  } else {
    i = 0; 
  } 
  var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>";
  $('#ImageDiv').html(imgStr); 
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share some code please?

Comment: 'code'
var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>"; This is the js used for calling image dynamically

Comment: Can you share you *entire* js code written for "dynamically calling images" and walk us through it? Are you appending `<img />` dynamically as well?

Comment: have you tried with a smaller image? Sometimes it takes a while before an image is shown.

Comment: `code`
$("#ImageDiv").swiperight(function () {
            if (i < (imgURL.length - 1)) {
                i++
            } else {
                i = 0;
           }
        var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>";
        $('#ImageDiv').html(imgStr);
    });
this is the entire code i am using.

Comment: where comes var `i` from? did you try to `console.log` `imgURL[i]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this,

```
var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>";
 $('#ImageDiv').html(imgStr);
```

Can you do this,

```
$("#ImageDiv img").attr('src', imgURL[i]);
```